# How do I import my programs from makecode (Chromebook) to my EV3 robot

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, programming

While using makecode I wanted to import my file to my EV3 robot but it says that I have to connect my EV3 robot to my computer and then move the file to the robot. But since I'm on Chromebook I don't see the file of my robot and I don't know if there is a way to import programs from makecode to my EV3 robot. If this is not clear I could put more information.

Comment: Did you install the v1.10E firmware on your EV3?